# Setting custom RequestButton button

Tags: ios, uber-api

I have just started exploring the Uber iOS Sdk. I was checking for RequestButton and have noticed that its not taking any frame which we are passing. Is it possible to put button on desired location of a view?

```
let button = RequestButton(colorStyle:.White)
view.addSubview(button)
button.frame = CGRectMake(100,300, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add the RequestButton in a desired location. The RequestButton is positioned with Auto Layout (or Constraint Based Layout) rather than Frame-Based Layout. See Apple's notes on [Auto Layout Versus Frame-Based Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW4).

Auto Layout guarantees resizing when the frame changes orientation and for different device sizes. In Auto Layout, you need to place UIViews based on their *relative* position to other views.

Here is an example of how you would center a RequestButton (`button`) inside a parent UIView (`inView`)

```
func centerButton(forButton button: RequestButton, inView: UIView) {
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // position constraints
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: inView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: inView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        // add constraints to view
        inView.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an easier way but I found this solution for positioning the Uber RequestButton using frame based layouts.

Place the request button inside a wrapper UIView. Set the constraints on the wrapper view via [Christine Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34465139/1552116)'s answer. Then you can position the wrapper's frame and the RequestButton will move with it

```
// MyView.swift
let uber = RequestButton()
let uberWrapper = UIView()

uberWrapper.addSubview(uber)
self.addSubview(uberWrapper)

//Set constraints
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: uber, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: uberWrapper, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: uber, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: uberWrapper, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

// add constraints to view
uberWrapper.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])

//layoutSubviews()
//set your origin
uberWrapper.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointMake(0, 0), size: uber.intrinsicContentSize())
```